# VB 2008 move a drawing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm beginning to learn about 2D graphics, and I have made a program in which a small space ship rotates, with some tutorials I found, then when i tried to move it I realized that .location does not work for bitmaps... Suggestions? I just want to move the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you draw your ship, move the coordinate origin with

```
g.TranslateTransform(dx,dy);
```

where `g` is the `Graphics` object you are drawing with.

Comment: doesnt work says "translateTransform" is not part of system.drawing.bitmap

Comment: WOW. :D I got it!!! THANK YOU! I played around whith Translate Transform and got it, thank you for putting me in the correct direction!